# command to print all the lines until the first match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to print all the lines from a file before the first match. I have the same entries again in the file, but I don't need that lines. Tried
awk "{print} /${pattern}/ {exit}" and sed "/$pattern/q" (my serach is based on a variable). But both these commands are printing all the line before the last match
ex: my file is like
abc
bcd
def
xyz
def
lmno
def
xvd

when my pattern is 'def', i just need abc and bcd . but the above commands are printing, all the lines before the last 'def'. could you please provide some idea

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
awk '!'"/${pattern}/{print} /${pattern}/ {exit}"  input_file.txt
```